# What is service detection?

Tags: service, detection

I'm taking a course in computer communication and I am trying to find and atricle about service detection to understand what it is and to solve an assignment.

But i can't find any, anyone that can explain what it is and what to search for to find a article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you are actually looking for is [Service *Discovery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery).